# Why do I need to use locks with semaphore

Tags: c#, locking, semaphore

I want to create Queue while defining max size with semaphore.

Enque will add item and deque will delete item

```
public void Enque(T item)
    {
        semaphore.WaitOne();
        privateQueue.Enqueue(item);
```

While googling similar situations I found out that sometimes locks are used 
like this

```
semaphore.WaitOne();
lock(lock)
privateQueue.Enqueue(item);
```

Why do we need to add locks with semaphore?
Thanks

Comment: What is the initialisation of Semaphore? If it's `new Semaphore(0, 1)` then you may not need to use a lock, since use of such a semaphore will only allow one thread access to the resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your semaphore allows concurrent access to the queue (by allowing a maximum count > 1), then enqueuing and dequeuing must be done in a thread-safe manner.

Alternatively, you could use a queue that's already thread-safe, such as `ConcurrentQueue<T>`, and then you wouldn't need a lock - provided that the lock **only protected the queue itself**. If the lock encompassed more than that (it's hard to say from the code snippet in your question) then you may need it anyway.